# Execute the jar compiled by Gradle, cause "there is no main class"

Tags: gradle, jar

The version of the gradle is 6.3-all. And here is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.72'
}

group 'com.dennis'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.runtime.collect { zipTree(it) }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.dennis.tcp.robot.RobotClient'
    }
}

dependencies {
    /*...*/
}


compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
```

And here is settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'robot'
```

And here is the main class:

```java
package com.dennis.tcp.robot;

/*import ignored*/

public class RobotClient {

    private static final String URL = "192.168.10.140";
    private static final int PORT = 9760;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NioEventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        try {
            bootstrap.group(group)
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE,true)
                    .handler(new RobotClientInitializer());

            ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(URL, PORT).sync();
            future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

The packaging progress went well but the output jar cannot be executed and give the Exception of `no main class`
The jar file shows the main class RobotClient is compiled indeed. However, the `java -jar` cannot execute or find the mainclass.
Why did this happend?

Comment: Does `com.dennis.tcp.robot.RobotClient` have a `public static void main(String[] args)` method?

Comment: I have added some details, and there is a `public static main` in deed

Comment: You are using the Kotlin plugin but writing a Java class. Just want to be sure that the class is in `src/main/java` and not the kotlin folder? If so, you could open the built jar file (either with a program like [JD-GUI](https://java-decompiler.github.io/) or just a normal zip program) and check if your class file is there and if the MANIFEST.MF file is correct). Also, the way you construct the über jar probably won't work because you reference the deprecated `runtime` configuration. Use `runtimeClasspath` instead.